# AJAX call, hook_menu the requested url does not exist

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create an AJAX request. I first implemented `hook_menu()` and added this code in that hook.

```php
$items['aug_store_front/get-products/ajax'] = array(
  'title' => t('Get products from specific product group'),
  'page callback' => 'aug_store_get_products',
  'access callback' => array('access content'),
);
```

The code for the page callback is the following one.

```php
function aug_store_get_products($value) {
  if($_POST['id'] = 6) {
    return drupal_json_output(array('status' => 'success'));
  }
  return drupal_json_output(array('status' => 'failure'));
}
```

I added this codein a JavaScript file.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".view-aug-store-frontpage li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/aug_store_front/get-products/ajax', {
      id: 6,
    });
  });
});
```

When I click on the list element, the request is made, but I get a 404 error.

> [image: screenshot]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused `access arguments` with `access callback`. It should be:

```
$items['aug_store_front/get-products/ajax'] = array(
  'title' => t('Get products from specific product group'),
  'page callback' => 'aug_store_get_products',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

Comment: The JS wouldn't cause a 404 - have you cleared cached and made sure the `hook_menu` implementation has `return $items;` in it?

Comment: If the function's named correctly, the module's enabled, and you have clean URLs enabled, that really should work

Comment: If any dynamic paths work, i.e. you're not accessing the site via http://example.com/?q=/some/path, clean URLs should be enabled